# Does a parent component's state change triggers render method on all the child components?

Tags: reactjs

Suppose I change the state for the root component. So is it going to re render all the child components in the browser ?

Answer (score 0):

> Does a parent component's state change triggers render method on all
>   the child components?

**May not be the case always.**

- For instance if at any level in the children you have a `PureComponent` and the props to the component doesn't change it will not trigger a re-render of that component and all of its children.
- Also in a case when one of your Child component implements a `shouldComponentUpdate` to check for prop change, it may not call a re-render for it and its children if the props to it didn't change.
- An unlikely case is when you have a shouldComponentUpdate in the component itself where for a particular/any state change you return false causing the render to not be called.

However if any of the above case is not true, `render` function in all the children will be called